# Counting missing files or records in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api, looker-studio

I have a table in Big Query used for monitoring purpose. This table shows at least the following information (fields):

```
+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+----------------+
|           timestamp            | data_type | file_name | status | loaded records |
+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+----------------+
| 2020-04-02 19:51:11.822674 UTC | aa        | e.gz      | OK     |           2293 |
| 2020-04-02 20:00:06.261044 UTC | bb        | g.gz      | OK     |             25 |
| 2020-04-02 20:02:07.304114 UTC | cc        | cd.csv    | OK     |            298 |
| 2020-04-02 20:09:26.708910 UTC | dd        | ab.csv    | OK     |          49448 |
| 2020-04-02 20:31:00.662977 UTC | ee        | ad.csv    | OK     |           4805 |
| 2020-04-02 20:37:41.459875 UTC | ff        | f.bz      | OK     |            245 |
+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+----------------+
```

Timestamp is timestamp when file is received by the system

Data_type signifies what data type and source of information the system collects from data source. Data type also indicates number of files expected from each data source, and they vary from source to source. Some sources are expected to generate hourly, some daily, some every 15 minutes and some every 5 minutes.

Let's assume in the table above data_type aa and bb are produced every 5 minutes; hence the expected occurrence is 12 files per hour. Data type cc and dd are produced every hour and data_type ee and ff are produced daily.

Filename is name of the file associated with datatype. So the frequency of this file appear in the report hourly or daily depends of data type.  Just to be precise, if it is associated with data type aa and bb then there is 12 files will show per hour for that data type or 288 per day. For hourly data type such as cc and dd it is expected once per hour or 12 occurrences per day, and so on so forth.

For various reasons there are missing files observed from time to time, which will affect data quality.

I would like to count missing files of each data_type for a desired period of time; possibly hourly (applies to hourly data type), daily (for all data types)) and monthly (for all data types). This will  be visualized using visualization tools such as Google DataStudio or tableau.

Expected result (table) would be

**Date(or dateTime) Data_type count_missing_files**

How do I do this? new table in bq and what would be the query for this? 
Can I simply do this directly with visualization with added logic instead of creating a new table? If yes, how to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in Tableau. Create a calculated field showing the expected number of files. How best to do this depends on how you want to report it. If reporting hourly then this would be at the hourly level, which will sum up to daily. If reporting daily then this would be the expected number per day.

Example of hourly calculated field

```
CASE [Data Type]
WHEN 'aa' THEN 12
WHEN 'bb' THEN 12
...
END
```

If the "target" formula is correct it is then simple to calculate the difference between target record count and actual number of records with a straightforward sum. For example:

```
SUM([Target) - SUM([Number of Records])
```

Comment: This should be a very simple logic but when I applied this

CASE [Data Type]
WHEN 'aa' THEN 12
WHEN 'bb' THEN 12
...
END

in tableau, the hourly  files simply shows number of  files (records) multiplied by 12 and  if I changed this to 1 then it is just the same as number of files value for that data type instead of expected number of files for that period.  For expected daily records, it shows 3456 instead of 288.

Also, when this SUM([Target) - SUM([Number of Records]) applied of course the result is incorrect.  

Any hint or suggestion?

Comment: Yes, of course, you'll have more than one record per data type. I should have thought of that...

Comment: How do you intend on showing this data? The solution may depend on how you want to show the data. You have the option of reference lines, using the target as a dimension rather than measure (i.e. a constant), blending the targets from a different data source and also getting more complex with the target calculation. Best option depends on desired output.

Comment: Actually I wanted to show the missing files for each data type in a some forms; histogram chart over time that can be aggregated as desired (i.e. hourly, daily, weekly, monthly) and  in table format (e.g. date time, data type and missing record (file)).

Also, wanted to show percentage of received records against target for each data type over desired period (i.e., daily, monthly)

Comment: I think target calculation gives me more flexibility;hence preferred option.

Comment: I owe you a response to this, apologies, I haven't had the time to look at SO much recently, will try and get to it tomorrow. It's not a 5 min solution so can't do it today unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As you stay in your question, you can employ BigQuery to generate a table to be plotted using Data-Studio.

You can use the below query to retrieve a table with the number of expected files within a certain time-range interval denoted by the difference between `<END TIMESTAMP>` and `<START TIMESTAMP>`. I have made use of a WITH clause where the data you show in the description is recorded together with the extra field `frecuency_file_generation_minutes`. In this column I have added the time that takes to produce the different files (in minutes): 5 for `"aa"` and `"bb"`, 60 for `"cc"` and `"dd"` and 24*60 for `"ee"` and `"ff"`. Computing `time_window_minutes/frecuency_file_generation_minutes` provides the amount of expected files within the specified range interval.

```
WITH
  data AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP "2020-04-02 19:51:11.822674" AS timestamp,
    "aa" AS data_type,
    "e.gz" AS file_name,
    "OK" AS status,
    2293 AS loaded_records,
    5 AS frecuency_file_generation_minutes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP "2020-04-02 20:00:06.261044" AS timestamp,
    "bb" AS data_type,
    "g.gz" AS file_name,
    "OK" AS status,
    25 AS loaded_records,
    5 AS frecuency_file_generation_minutes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP "2020-04-02 20:02:07.304114" AS timestamp,
    "cc" AS data_type,
    "cd.gz" AS file_name,
    "OK" AS status,
    298 AS loaded_records,
    60 AS frecuency_file_generation_minutes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP "2020-04-02 20:09:26.708910" AS timestamp,
    "dd" AS data_type,
    "ab.gz" AS file_name,
    "OK" AS status,
    49448 AS loaded_records,
    60 AS frecuency_file_generation_minutes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP "2020-04-02 20:31:00.662977" AS timestamp,
    "ee" AS data_type,
    "ad.gz" AS file_name,
    "OK" AS status,
    4805 AS loaded_records,
    24*60 AS frecuency_file_generation_minutes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP "2020-04-02 20:37:41.459875" AS timestamp,
    "ff" AS data_type,
    "f.gz" AS file_name,
    "OK" AS status,
    245 AS loaded_records,
    24*60 AS frecuency_file_generation_minutes ) 
SELECT
  *, 
  FLOOR(time_window_minutes/frecuency_file_generation_minutes) AS expected_files
FROM (
  SELECT 
  *,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(<END TIMESTAMP>, <START TIMESTAMP>, MINUTE) time_window_minutes
  FROM data
  WHERE
    timestamp BETWEEN <START TIMESTAMP>
    AND <END TIMESTAMP>
  )
```

You can compare the expected files `expected_files` with the actually generated ones within a given time interval. In the output table I have included all the fields but you can adapt this query to better suit your use case.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but it seems this query requires pre-defined time window?

What I would like to crate is simply timestamp, number of files received, number of files expected and the ratio between received and expected, but time span depends on the chart I choose; hence the criteria will adjust accordingly.

For 5 minutes file type, daily expected file is 288, but if I want to show this per month then it will adjust to number of days in that month, such as 30*288 = 8640 or 31*288=8928 files per month. Similarly for data_type that is expected hourly.
Any hint?